# setSelectedNavigationItem(position) for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to the tabs to change with the PageChangeListener as it does with ActionBar

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```

Since I am now using Toolbar and Tablayout for Fragments I cannot change the Tab with onPageSelected in ViewPager.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager mViewPager) {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, (float) 2323.22,true);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)));
    }

}
```

SectionsPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new FeedsFragment();
            case 1:
                return new InboxFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually problem is that your tab can't scroll in viewpager ?

Comment: @kishan then how should I implement it with the onPageSelected. Where I want to show the tabs on PageSelected.

Comment: wait i will post my code with its work fine for me .

Comment: @kishan Thanks waiting for your code :)

Answer (score 0):

here is my activity code which can i use for tab selection

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PageAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 3);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                Downloads frag1 = (Downloads) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                frag1.refersh();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

In onpageseleted i done 1 page refersh method so u can refersh any page into that. try this.

**Pageadater.java**

```
 public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = new InstaDown();
            break;
        case 1:
            f = new Downloads();
            break;
        case 2:
            f = new guide();
            break;
    }
    return f;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    CharSequence f = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = "Home";
            break;
        case 1:
            f = "Downloads";
            break;
        case 2:
            f = "Tutorial";
            break;
    }
    return f;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: What is downloads?

Comment: what is downloads?

Comment: it is my fragment. which fragment i want to refersh . it was just refersh method which was in download fragment. forget that .i think you made your pageadapter so apply that code it can be work .

Comment: it still doesnt work. I want tabs to change on page selected.

Comment: can i see your pageadapter ?

Comment: I have added the sectionspageradapter class

Comment: this my my full code its work fine fore me try this .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107332/discussion-between-savita-and-kishan).